# How to get Formula Behind Conditional Formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I get formula applied behind conditional Formatting for highlighting Cells?

Conditional Formatting is applied based on text in each cell of Test Result column(third column).
[image: Column is highlighted]

Formulas List: 
[image: Total 5 Formulas are applied]

Purpose is to reuse (copy paste) the formula in other sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is shown in your first screenshot. The dialog has the formula in the column "Rule applied (in order shown)". These rules use the out of the box settings to format cells based on their values, so the "formula" is not accessible for editing.

But the format can be copied to other cells very easily.

Here are the steps:

- Select the cell with the conditional format and copy it
- click the cell where you want to apply the same format
- use Paste Special > Format to paste just the format to the selected cell

Edit: If you don't use the built-in conditional formats but instead select "Use a formula to determine ...", you can construct the formulas manually.
[image]

There is no automated way to convert the existing out-of-the-box rules to fomulas. You will need to use your human understanding of the logic and appy this to formulas. So, for example, if the selected cell is H3, you can us this formula

```
=H3="Fail"
```

and format the cell with red font and light red background. Note that there are no $ signs in the reference to the cell H3. If you copy that format to another cell, it will apply to that other current cell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware about copying format (by format painter and paste special). Looking for way to get raw formula.

Comment: Well there ***IS*** no "raw formula" for the built-in conditional formats that you use in these cells. What are you trying to achieve? If you want to copy the conditional formatting to another cell, I've shown you how to do that. That's what you asked for `Purpose is to reuse (copy paste) the formula in other sheets.` If you want something else, first accept this solution, because it does exactly what you asked for. Then, feel free to ask another question with a different scope.

Comment: I added a way to achieve the same conditional formatting with a rule that uses a formula. If that solves your problem, please do your part of the deal and mark the answer as explained in the [Tour].